# Could not load ArcGis Runtime(RuntimeCoreNet200_3.dll)

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, arcgis, esri

Hello i have a WPF application that was running fine and well with esri version 200.0 and net version 6.0

After we upgraded to net version 8 and esri version 200.3 im getting the following exception
(after calling `ArcGitRuntimeEnviroment.Initialize()`):

*Could not load ArcGis Runtime(RuntimeCoreNet200_3.dll) or one of it dependencies Ensure "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable" is installed* with inner exception : *Unable to load DLL "RuntimeCoreNet200_3.dll"  or one of it dependencies: the specified module could not be found(0x8007007E)*

And when i checked the AcGisRuntime200.3 folder all i see the resources folder(the .dll file seems to be missing)

I have tried the following solutions [Solution 1](https://community.esri.com/t5/net-maps-sdk-questions/compatibility-issue-with-esri-arcgisruntime-nuget/m-p/1364788)  [Solution 2](https://community.esri.com/t5/net-maps-sdk-questions/exception-in-net-8-wpf-app-when-loading-runtime/m-p/1349762)

im using the following nugets

Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Hydography 200.3

Esri.ArcGISRuntime.WPF 200.3

Esri.ArcGISRuntime 200.3

window version 1809(OS build 17763.5458)